# Group collection and count some fields using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this Model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const donationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id:{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required:true
  },
  title:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  description:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  city:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  photo:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  quantity:{
    type:Number,
    required:true,
    default:1
  },
  status:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    default:"En cours"
  },
  category:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  subscribers:{
    type:[],
    required:false
  },
  value:{
    type:Number,
    required:false
  },
  attribution_date:{
    type:Date,
    required:false
  }
},
  {timestamps:true})

  donationSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    next()
  })

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Donation', donationSchema)
```

in my router I want to aggregate the collection based on the field user_id and get the count of the recurrence of user_id on the collection, the sum of the **value** field per each user_id and the count of elements in the **subscribers** array per each user_id.

This is possible in SQL but this is my first experience with mongoose so if you could help me I would be gratefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$user_id",
    "countOfUsers": { "$sum": 1 },  //Count the number of user ids
    "subscribersCount": { "$sum": { "$size": "$subscribers" }}  // Get the size of the subscribers array and make summation
  }}
])
```